# React: how-to override child component

Tags: reactjs

Which is the best way to override a child component?

1. check if *this.props.children* != null
2. passing the component with *props*
3. ?

Example component

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <ChildComponent />
    </div>
  }
}
```

**Solution 1**

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      {this.props.children ? this.props.children : <DefaultChildComponent/>}
    </div>
  }
}

<ParentComponent><MyChildComponent/></ParentComponent>
```

**Solution 2**

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      {this.props.child}
    </div>
  }
}
Parent.defaultProps = { child: <DefaultChildComponent /> }

const myChildComponent = <MyChildComponent/>
<ParentComponent child={myChildComponent}/>
```

**Solution 3?**

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is slightly confusing as you are checking for `this.props.children` but then rendering other components rather than the `children`.

I would have thought the best way would be;

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

  render() {

    <div>       
       {
           this.props.children
           ? this.props.children
           : <DefaultChildComponent />
       }
    </div>
  }
}
```

Then use it as either;

```
<ParentComponent />
```

Which just renders your default child component

or

```
<ParentComponent><div>Can Be Any Child</div></ParentComponent>
```

Which you can pass any component is as this children which will then be rendered.

Comment: I *think* React treats `children` like any other prop so in theory you should be able to set a default value, means you could in effect always render the children.

Comment: @James you mean: ParentComponent.defaultProps = { children: <DefaultChildComponent/> }?

Comment: @Pietro If the "DefaultChildComponent" is always going to be the default, then Solution 1/My answer, to me, is the best way. I can't see any point in assigning the default component to the children prop when it is never going to change

Comment: @TimBJames: James has a point. If you set the default for this.props.children, you can avoid the if else condition and simply always render {this.props.children}

Comment: @Pietro It will depend where you set the default props though. If you are setting these outside of the component, then you still run the risk of them not being set if you are using the component elsewhere. You are leaving yourself open to errors. If you make sure you are always setting default props, then you are really just over complicating things when Solution 1 does the job and is easy/clear to understand what is going on.

Comment: @TimBJames not sure I understand the concern, setting default props externally doesn't make sense so not sure why you'd ever do that. Both ways work, my suggestion was just leveraging the mechanism that already exists and keeps the code *slightly* cleaner - not a big deal which way the OP wants to do it tbf.